# How to bind ASP.net datatable from javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, datatable, bind

I am using Bootstrap datatable (https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)
for show datatable in aspx page.

I am getting data from database.

I want this from javascript/ajax and refresh table every seconds.
What is the best way?

I am trying this. Set breakpoint on fillFileTable but breakpoint not work; not entering breakpoint.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#filesTable').DataTable({
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "sAjaxSource": "files.aspx/fillFileTable"
        });
});


[WebMethod]
public static string fillFileTable()
{
   DataTable dt = //...(get table from database)

   JavaScriptSerializer js=new JavaScriptSerializer();  
   js.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;  

   return js.Serialize(dt);

}
```

Comment: "not work" is not an error message or problem description. What have you done to debug this? Look in your browser's dev tools to see any errors in the console or network tab, set breakpoints in the server method to try and see if anything goes wrong there. Check the output of the server method to ensure it's in the correct format required by the plugin. If you can't fix it after that, give us the information from your debugging, and show us the server method code as well so we understand more about what is happening. Remember we cannot read your screen or your mind.

Comment: edited. Set breakpoint, but code not entering breakpoint.

Comment: ok so time to debug the client-side...does the AJAX request ever get sent? Is the URL correct?

Comment: What URL is called from ajax. Can you check this in the Dev Tools. Is the files.aspx in root?